# How can I make a datepicker customization?

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chS1z.png)

Hello to all the community, I need that my datepicker can have the american timetable year, month, day because it appears in latin time, how can I configure that.

I also need that my datepicker shows like this
2022-03-02 and not to show 2022/03/02 can you help me?

Comment: Please take the advice the text is giving you and "enter [an] image description [there]". Don't just leave it set to the default. Also, please show what research you've done; most of these components have documentation readily available; was there something confusing about that documentation that prevented you from following it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Angular Material documentation you can see how to configure the datepicker, at internationalization section: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#internationalization

See also MomentDateModule formats section:

You can pick from the parse formats documented here:
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/